# File not found exception when fetching the video path from Intent delivered to onActivityResult()

Tags: android

I'm new to android programming and need help for this problem which I'm encountering in capturing video file and uploading it on server. 
My activity 1 starts with using native video capture -

```
private void recordVideo(){
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new 
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri videoUri = intent.getData();
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    Log.d("Getting video path ", videoUri.getPath() );
  }
}
```

and I upload to server by passing the intent to activity 2. However, while uploading the file to server, my app is getting crashed because my File object is not able to get the file path. 
An example of file path, which I'm logging is -
**/external/video/media/18518**.
I'm not using any external storage and when I'm browsing my Lenovo K4 note on which I'm testing this using file browser, the file is not present in

/external/video/media directory. Instead the video is getting stored in

"/Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera/test.mp4"

As a workaround, I hardcoded this file path in my activity 2 code, which is reading the file and uploading it to server but still getting file not found exception -

```
            int readedBytes;
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            File file = new File("/Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera/test.mp4");
            InputStream insputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            long length = file.length();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
            insputStream.read(bytes);
            while((readedBytes = insputStream.read(buf)) >0 ){
                bos.write(buf, 0, readedBytes);
            }
            insputStream.close();


java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera/test.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-04 00:06:14.432 23628-24496/com.example.jayant.healthapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
05-04 00:06:14.433 23628-24496/com.example.jayant.healthapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
```

Any pointer in this problem will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

> However, while uploading the file to server, my app is getting crashed because my File object is not able to get the file path.

You are not getting a file. You are getting a `Uri`. A `Uri` is not a file. In particular, the `Uri` that you are getting has a `content` scheme, which can point to whatever the camera app wants it to point to.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

> I hardcoded this file path in my activity 2 code

That is not a valid file path on any Android device.

> Instead the video is getting stored in "/Internal Storage/DCIM/Camera/test.mp4"

No, it is not. You appear to be confusing what some file manager might be reporting with what is actually used on an Android device itself.

Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` to get the device's own filesystem path that should map to that `DCIM/` directory that you are seeing.

Comment: Apologies for late reply but thanks for the solution, it worked !